# WP8.1 app crashes when navigating to another page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

It's a data-bound windows phone 8.1 (universal) app. When I navigate to a detailed view of the item from the main page it works like a charm. When I use the same code to navigate from another page to the same detailed one, my app closes and I get no exception. Code is the same as in the hub default sample when you open a new hub project.
This is the code I use to navigate to he page.

```
 private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
            // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
            var itemId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;

            if (!Frame.Navigate(typeof(Session), itemId))
            {
                throw new Exception(this.resourceLoader.GetString("NavigationFailedExceptionMessage"));
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the code I use to handle the loading

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {

        // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
        var item = await SampleDataSource.GetItemAsync((string)e.NavigationParameter);
        this.DefaultViewModel["Item"] = item;


    }
```

The code stops after hitting the last bracket and the app exits. Until then it works as it should, the values are correct and it finds the specific item!

Comment: Does the "other page" also pass an itemId?

Comment: Yes, using the same code. It get the itemid correctly. Which is why I find this hard to understand.I use the same code and it works the same way.And the it just stops.

Comment: Except for the LoadState handler - are there any async void methods involved in the chain? Those are almost impossible to debug. You could also try this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/10/16/strategies-for-handling-errors-in-your-windows-store-apps.aspx

Comment: No unhandled exception found/caught.  There is no other async in this part of the code. Also, it exits the async with the correct parameters and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/6d1a6be3-096e-4090-a4bd-30d1293697b3/windows-phone-81-update-1-access-violation-when-navigating-using-tapped-event?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK) and changed my code to

```
 private async void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        {

            var itemId = ((SampleDataItem)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Frame.Navigate(typeof(Session), itemId));


        }
    }
```

I still don't understand this error, but it is now solved.